# Class composition in Entity Framework 4

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Say I have a very simple class structure, more for convenience than anything.

```
class A{
    [Column("someValue")]
    public int someValue{get; set;}
}

[Table("tableB")]
class B{
    [Column("somethingElse")]
    public int somethingElse{get; set;}
    public A somethingEncapsulated{get; set;}
}

[Table("tableC")]
class C{
    [Column("otherSomething")]
    public int otherSomething{get; set;}
    public A somethingEncapsulated{get; set;}
}
```

And the database structure, **which cannot be changed** looks so

```
tableB
------
somethingElse int
someValue int

tableC
-----
otherSomething int
someValue int
```

Is it possible to represent this structure in Entity Framework without eliminating class A?  If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by `without eliminating class A`?

Comment: Other alternative would be inheriting class `A` in class `B` and `C`. Then you can have several mapping options like  `Table per hierarchy`, `table per type`. http://vincentlauzon.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/entity-framework-4-1-inheritance-7/

Comment: @Jayantha, inheritance isn't an approach I thought of.  It may work but the first concern that springs to mind is the appropriateness of saying "B is a A".  What if B is already inheriting from another class, more appropriate class?

Answer (score 3):

You can use complex type mapping in this scenario.

```
[ComplextType]
public class A{
    [Column("someValue")]
    public int someValue{get; set;}
}
```

[Go through this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx)